# S3 & Nodejs Object Deletion False Success

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am trying to create a workflow with my delete method where I delete the file associated with my database record. Following the s3 documentation, I created a new s3 object, then set the options with a bucket and key (which I believe should just be the file path e.x. /username/picture-1.jpg') and then use the `.deleteObject` method to remove the file. With my current setup, I query the correct file, parse out the file path for the key and receive a "File successfully deleted" console log, but the file still exists in my s3 bucket. Any help?

**Example:**

note.fileAttachment = `https://working-test.s3.amazonaws.com/1/2016-08-06/file-test.png`

**Console log:**

```
    Here is the file attachment path: https://working-test.s3.amazonaws.com/1/2016-08-06/file-test.png
    /1/2016-08-06/file-test.png
    This is the file being deleted: /1/2016-08-06/file-test.png
File successfully deleted
```

**Route:**

```
.delete(function(req, res){
        models.Note.findOne({
            where: {
                userId: req.user.userId,
                noteId: req.params.noteId
            }
        }).then(function(note){
            aws.config.update({accessKeyId: config.awsAccessKeyId, secretAccessKey: config.awsSecretAccessKey, region: 'us-east-1'});

            console.log('Here is the file attachment path: ' + note.fileAttachment);

            function s3Key(link){
                var parsedUrl = url.parse(link);
                var fileName = parsedUrl.path;
                console.log(fileName);
                return fileName;
            }
            var awsKeyPath = s3Key(note.fileAttachment);

            console.log("This is the file being deleted: " + awsKeyPath);

            var s3 = new aws.S3()
            var options = {
              Bucket: config.awsBucket,
              Key: note.fileAttachment
            }

            s3.deleteObject(options, function(err, data){
                if(data){
                    console.log("File successfully deleted");
                } else {
                    console.log("Check with error message " + err);
                }
            });
        }).then(function(){
            models.Note.destroy({
                where: {
                    userId: req.user.userId,
                    noteId: req.params.noteId           
                }
            });
        }).then(function(note){
            req.flash('info', 'Note was successfully deleted.');
            res.send('Note was deleted.');
        });
    });
```

Comment: why do you have `Key: annotation.fileAttachment` in your code ? its not referenced elsewhere and you had `awsKeyPath` pointing to the s3 key of the object to be deleted

Comment: Any delete operation always succeeds in S3 because of the REST concept of idempotent requests.  If you try to delete an object from a bucket, and you have permission to do so, then after the delete operation completes, there is definitely no such object in the bucket... hence, you succeeded... even if the object was already deleted or never existed.  @FrédéricHenri has pinpointed your first problem, though.  You say you're going to delete one thing, then delete something entirely different.  Remember, too, that object keys do not properly have a leading slash.

Comment: @FrédéricHenri that is a mistake to my code. It actually exists in my code as `note.fileAttachment`. This is not a part of my problem

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Frederic's point was a mistake in my question that I edited. I think my issue might have something more to do with the proper format of my object key value. Can you elaborate on the leading slash removal and give me an example of what my file path should actually look like based on my console logs above?

Comment: The error is still there. `Key: note.fileAttachment` is almost certainly wrong and should be `Key: awsKeyPath`.  Above that, I suspect `s3Key()` should actually `return fileName.substr(1);`